# sfdx force:org:open I can't open in chrome on my macbook pro 2016

Tags: salesforcedx

I have set up my salesforce environment on macbook pro 16 inch.
In macbook pro 16 I just can't get sfdx open to start from chrome but it always start from safari. What I am missing here. I have installed the latest sfdx-cli and install debugger for chrome in visual studio code and set my default browser to be chrome. my vs code version is 1.45.1 and chrome is 80.0.3987 on MacOS Catalina version 10.15.3. What is the best way to debug this?

Comment: Can you try running the command, then immediately follow it with `tail ~/.sfdx/sfdx.log` and provide the output (feel free to redact any personal info from there, just need any errors, etc).

Comment: Apparently it was permission issue. I always had to sudo to run sfdx command because of some of files are owned by root. after setting the file to owned by current user it started to open in the chrome.